# streamlining script

Tags: python, function, dictionary, syntax

Question from a Python newbie. As a practice project, I am coding a simple game for one of my siblings. The basic idea is to create an agent loadout from various lists of equipment stored in a database.

I am looking for a way to streamline my code, which works, but is very clunky and long-winded.

I have made a few lists as follows:

```
assault_rifles = ["M4A1-S", "AK-47", "FN Scar 17S", "AAC HoneyBadger", "HK G36 RDS"]
side_arms = ["FN Five-Seven", "SIG Saur P250", "M1911", "HK P30L", "CZ P-10 C"]
precision_rifles = ["CZ TSR", "HK PSG-1", "Mossberg MVP Precision", "SVD Dragunov", "Tikka T3x TAC A1"]
agent_loadout = []
```

When the agent has logged in, he is asked which database he would like to access, and then from that database, he can select an item to append to a list called "agent_loadout." Now, I made it work with while loops and if/elif/else statements, but doing it this way requires huge, repetitive blocks of code, like this:

```
while True:
        dbChoice = input(": ")
        if dbChoice in ("1", "2", "3", "4"):
            break
        print("Invalid entry")
# After this, repeat code for "2" "3", etc
    if dbChoice == "1":
        print("Accessing Assault Rifle Database")
        print("The following Assault Rifles are available:")
        for AR in (assault_rifles):
            print(assault_rifles.index(AR) + 1, AR)
        selection = int(input("Enter the number of the item to add to your loadout: "))
        agent_loadout.append(assault_rifles[selection-1])
        print("Your Current Loadout:")
        for item in (agent_loadout):
            print(agent_loadout.index(item) + 1, item)
```

and then I have to repeat the code from where I placed the comment, assigning "2" to [side_arms], "3" to [precision_rifles], etc.

So, my question is: How could I condense this into an easier-to-read, more streamlined script.

Here is one idea I had:

1. I could make a dictionary like this:

```
{"1":assault_rifles,"2":side_arms,"3":precision_rifles}
```

perhaps also make each of the above lists into a dictionary with its own keyword values,
and then make a function like this (in pseudo-code):

```
def choose_db():
     have agent input choice of database
     print database, corresponding to agents choice of number
     have agent input choice of weapon
     append chosen weapon to agent_loadout list
```

Is this function a viable solution? If so, I could use help with the syntax of how to assign an integer key (or maybe number string?) input to return the corresponding value from a dictionary! If anyone knows a good syntax for that, please post. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont get the title, what does this have to do with absolute values

Comment: The question seems unfocused, so it’d unlikely to help future users. Please reduce it to one specific, clear question. (See [ask].)

Comment: @Luke, sorry about the title. It was from another question which I abandoned and accidentally used the open thread to post this question. It's been ammended.

Comment: @Arya, the question is looking for advice on how to condense a script I have that works but is clunky. I provided one example which I think would work but I am unsure how to syntax.